# HTML5 Geolocation API is not working on JSFiddle

Tags: html, geolocation, jsfiddle

I have below mentioned JSFidle.But it's not working.Can you say why's that ?

**Note:** I want to run it on JSFiddle.It should show the Latitude and Longitude.

[JSFiddle Geolocation](http://jsfiddle.net/aspmastery/3eXpm/)

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have your JavaScript set to run in the `load` event (the second drop down on the left). The function `getLocation` only exists within the scope of that `load` handler, not in the global scope you're trying to call it from.

It [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/3eXpm/5/) if you change it to 'No wrap - in <body>'